# ElasticSearch - RestHighLevelClient with scrollAPI throwing `Suppressed: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: entity content is too long`

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am fetching `100k` documents using RestHighLevelClient with Scroll API for that approach am getting the below error.

`Suppressed: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: entity content is too long`

Please find the below error for `RestHighLevelClient`

```
D:\Karthikeyan\ElasticSearch\ElasticSearch_Tesing\target>java -jar ElasticSearch
Utility-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Jul 13, 2018 3:11:59 PM com.es.utility.DocumentIndex main
INFO: Started Indexing the Document.....
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configurati
on: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'log4j2.debug' to sh
ow Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no fur
ther information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEv
ent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:171)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEv
ents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:145)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute
(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:348)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.exe
cute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:192)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(Cl
oseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Suppressed: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: entity content is t
oo long [223328895] for the configured buffer limit [104857600]
                at org.elasticsearch.client.HeapBufferedAsyncResponseConsumer.on
EntityEnclosed(HeapBufferedAsyncResponseConsumer.java:76)
                at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.AbstractAsyncResponseConsumer.re    final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L)); //part of Scroll API
    searchRequest.scroll(scroll); //part of Scroll API
sponseReceived(AbstractAsyncResponseConsumer.java:131)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.responseReceiv
ed(MainClientExec.java:315)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerI
mpl.responseReceived(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:147)
                at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.respons
eReceived(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:303)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consume
Input(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:255)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputRea
dy(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputRea
dy(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputRead
y(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseI
OReactor.java:162)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEve
nt(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEve
nts(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(Ab
stractIOReactor.java:276)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIO
Reactor.java:104)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor
$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
                ... 1 more
```

So, i tried using `RestClient` instead of `RestHighLevelClient` by setting buffer size `static long BUFFER_SIZE = 500 * 1024 * 1024;`

But using `RestClient` am not sure how to use `ScrollAPI`. Because, i have to fetch more than `100k` documents from the index.

Please find my `RestHighLevelClient` code

```
public class DocumentIndexRestHighLevelClient {

    private final static String INDEX = "documents";  
    private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment"; 
    private final static String TYPE = "doc";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;
        Document doc=new Document();

        logger.info("Started Indexing the Document.....");

        try {
            restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        //Fetching Id, FilePath & FileName from Document Index. 
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
        searchRequest.types(TYPE);
        final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L)); //part of Scroll API
        searchRequest.scroll(scroll); //part of Scroll API
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
        searchSourceBuilder.size(120000); 
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
        String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId(); //part of Scroll API
        SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        long totalHits=searchResponse.getHits().totalHits;
        logger.info("Total Hits --->"+totalHits);

        //part of Scroll API -- Starts
        while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) { 
            SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId); 
            scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
            searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.searchScroll(scrollRequest);
            scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
            searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

            File all_files_path = new File("d:\\All_Files_Path.txt");
            File available_files = new File("d:\\Available_Files.txt");
            File missing_files = new File("d:\\Missing_Files.txt");

            int totalFilePath=1;
            int totalAvailableFile=1;
            int missingFilecount=1;

            Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;
            for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {

                String encodedfile = null;
                File file=null;

                Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();


                if(sourceAsMap != null) {  
                    doc.setId((int) sourceAsMap.get("id"));
                    doc.setApp_language(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("app_language")));

                }

                String filepath=doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename());

                logger.info("ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);


                try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(all_files_path, true))  ){
                    out.println("FilePath Count ---"+totalFilePath+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
                }

                file = new File(filepath);
                if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
                    try {
                          try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(available_files, true))  ){
                                out.println("Available File Count --->"+totalAvailableFile+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
                                totalAvailableFile++;
                            }
                        FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
                        encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
                        fileInputStreamReader.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Else block");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(missing_files, true));
                    out.println("Available File Count --->"+missingFilecount+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
                    out.close();
                    missingFilecount++;
                }

                jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
                jsonMap.put("id", doc.getId());
                jsonMap.put("app_language", doc.getApp_language());
                jsonMap.put("fileContent", encodedfile);

                String id=Long.toString(doc.getId());

                IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ATTACHMENT, "doc", id )
                        .source(jsonMap)
                        .setPipeline(ATTACHMENT);

                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new File("d:\\exception.txt"));
                try {
                    IndexResponse response = restHighLevelClient.index(request);

                } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
                    if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace(printStream);
                }

                totalFilePath++;
            }
        }

        ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest(); 
        clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
        ClearScrollResponse clearScrollResponse = restHighLevelClient.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest);
        boolean succeeded = clearScrollResponse.isSucceeded();
        ////part of Scroll API -- Ends
        logger.info("Indexing done.....");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size parameter should be set to how many docs you want to return per slice of the scroll not the whole thing. Start with something like 100 and slowly increase untill there is no more performance gain.

Comment: Yes ThankYou, its works for me. i have set it to `100` & `1000` receptively.  Now am getting different issue `search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id`.  I have created a separate question for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336462/elasticsearch-javaapi-searchscroll-search-context-missing-exception-reason