# ElasticSearch JavaAPI (SearchScroll)- search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am fetching more than `100k` documents from one index using `searchScroll` and adding one more field in all `100K` documents. Then again am inserting those documents into another new index.

Am using `SearchScroll` api also am setting the size `searchSourceBuilder.size(100)` i have increased the size to `searchSourceBuilder.size(1000)`. In both the cases am getting the below error after processing `18100` doucments ( when searchSourceBuilder.size(100) ) & `21098` documents( when searchSourceBuilder.size(1000)).

`search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id`

And, the error throws on this line `searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance().searchScroll(scrollRequest);`

Please find my complete error stack

```
Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception
[type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]]; nested: Elas
ticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_context_missing_exceptio
n, reason=No search context found for id [388]]];
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestR
esponse.java:177)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLeve
lClient.java:573)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(R
estHighLevelClient.java:549)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighL
evelClient.java:456)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEn
tity(RestHighLevelClient.java:429)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.searchScroll(RestHighLev
elClient.java:387)
        at com.es.utility.DocumentIndex.main(DocumentIndex.java:101)
        Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], ho
st [http://localhost:9200], URI [/_search/scroll], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not
 Found]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No
search context found for id [390]"},{"type":"search_context_missing_exception","
reason":"No search context found for id [389]"},{"type":"search_context_missing_
exception","reason":"No search context found for id [392]"},{"type":"search_cont
ext_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id [391]"},{"type":
"search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id [388
]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","pha
se":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":-1,"index":null,"reason":{"
type":"search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for i
d [390]"}},{"shard":-1,"index":null,"reason":{"type":"search_context_missing_exc
eption","reason":"No search context found for id [389]"}},{"shard":-1,"index":nu
ll,"reason":{"type":"search_context_missing_exception","reason":"No search conte
xt found for id [392]"}},{"shard":-1,"index":null,"reason":{"type":"search_conte
xt_missing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id [391]"}},{"shard"
:-1,"index":null,"reason":{"type":"search_context_missing_exception","reason":"N
o search context found for id [388]"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"search_context_miss
ing_exception","reason":"No search context found for id [388]"}},"status":404}
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.ja
va:357)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.ja
va:346)
                at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.
java:119)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerI
mpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:177)
                at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.process
Response(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436)
                at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputRe
ady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consume
Input(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputRea
dy(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputRea
dy(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputRead
y(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseI
OReactor.java:162)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEve
nt(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEve
nts(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(Ab
stractIOReactor.java:276)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIO
Reactor.java:104)
                at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor
$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_context_m
issing_exception, reason=No search context found for id [388]]]
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(Elasticsea
rchException.java:490)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchEx
ception.java:406)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(Elasticsea
rchException.java:435)
        at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.failureFromXContent(Elastics
earchException.java:594)
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestR
esponse.java:169)
        ... 6 more
```

Please find my java code :

```
public class DocumentIndex {

    private final static String INDEX = "documents"; 
    private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment"; 
    private final static String TYPE = "doc";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


        RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = null;

        Document doc=new Document();

        logger.info("Started Indexing the Document.....");

        try {
            restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        //Fetching Id, FilePath & FileName from Document Index. 
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
        searchRequest.types(TYPE);
        final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L)); //part of Scroll API
        searchRequest.scroll(scroll); //part of Scroll API
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();

        searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
        searchSourceBuilder.size(100); 
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance().search(searchRequest);
        String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId(); //part of Scroll API
        SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        long totalHits=searchResponse.getHits().totalHits;
        logger.info("Total Hits --->"+totalHits);

        //part of Scroll API -- Starts
        while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) { 
            SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId); 
            scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
            searchResponse = SearchEngineClient.getInstance().searchScroll(scrollRequest);
            scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
            searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

            File all_files_path = new File("d:\\All_Files_Path.txt");
            File available_files = new File("d:\\Available_Files.txt");
            File missing_files = new File("d:\\Missing_Files.txt");


            int totalFilePath=1;
            int totalAvailableFile=1;
            int missingFilecount=1;

            Map<String, Object> jsonMap ;
            for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {

                String encodedfile = null;
                File file=null;

                Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();


                if(sourceAsMap != null) {  
                    doc.setId((int) sourceAsMap.get("id"));
                    doc.setApp_language(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("app_language")));

                }

                String filepath=doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename());

                logger.info("ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);


                try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(all_files_path, true))  ){
                    out.println("FilePath Count ---"+totalFilePath+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
                }

                file = new File(filepath);
                if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
                    try {
                          try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(available_files, true))  ){
                                out.println("Available File Count --->"+totalAvailableFile+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
                                totalAvailableFile++;
                            }
                        FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
                        encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
                        fileInputStreamReader.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Else block");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(missing_files, true));
                    out.println("Available File Count --->"+missingFilecount+":::::::ID---> "+doc.getId()+"File Path --->"+filepath);
                    out.close();
                    missingFilecount++;
                }

                jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
                jsonMap.put("id", doc.getId());
                jsonMap.put("app_language", doc.getApp_language());
                jsonMap.put("fileContent", encodedfile);

                String id=Long.toString(doc.getId());

                IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(ATTACHMENT, "doc", id )
                        .source(jsonMap)
                        .setPipeline(ATTACHMENT);

                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new File("d:\\exception.txt"));
                try {
                    IndexResponse response = SearchEngineClient.getInstance2().index(request);

                } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
                    if (e.status() == RestStatus.CONFLICT) {
                    }
                    e.printStackTrace(printStream);
                }

                totalFilePath++;


            }


        }

        ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest(); 
        clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
        ClearScrollResponse clearScrollResponse = restHighLevelClient.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest);
        boolean succeeded = clearScrollResponse.isSucceeded();
        ////part of Scroll API -- Ends

        logger.info("Indexing done.....");

    }

}
```

Am using ES 6.2.3 version

Comment: You can try increasing the scroll keep alive time to a larger value and the scroll size to 10000 or so as well, it will all depend on the size of your individual docs

Comment: @sramalingam24 -  how to set scroll Size value..?

Answer (score 5):

You're getting that error because your search context is dead before getting and processing all the results so in order to solve this problem you should keep your search context alive for longer duration. Please refer [Keeping the search context alive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-search-context).

Increase the time value of your scroll.

```
new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(new_value));
```

increase the new_value to whatever suits your requirement.

Comment: i re-ran the same code with  `final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(30L));` (increased from 1L to 30L )and i also set `searchSourceBuilder.size(10000);` . So, it exactly indexed only `10000` documents and then it throws the same error

Comment: @Karthikeyan as it seems the `RestHighLevelClient` does not pass on the scroll timeout when calling `searchScroll`. Editing the request to `/_search/scroll?scroll=1m` solved it.